# using free national API to get data, "blocked by CORS policy" but works with postman/regular url

Tags: javascript, cors

I am trying to get books list from National Library API (free for public use).
It gives back JSON when visiting the URL in Chrome or hitting the endpoint with Postman.
However, I can't get rid of the error when trying to make it through `localhost`, while developing.
when I add: `{ mode: "no-cors"}`
to the `fetch` options,
I get a response back, but opaque type, so I can't read the data.

```js
fetch(
  `https://api.nli.org.il/openlibrary/search?api_key=uoX9ZMiaRMIBUF4pX0SEuGXMRpUqQIHrw5XuQKcE&query=title,exact,,AND;language,exact,heb&output_format=json&material_type=books`,
  {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
  }
).then((response) => console.log(response));
```

Error in console:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.nli.org.il/openlibrary/search?api_key=uoX9ZMiaRMIBUF4pX0SEuGXMRpUqQIHrw5XuQKcE&query=title,exact,%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9A,AND;language,exact,heb&output_format=json&material_type=books' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: The API in question doesn't seem to be configured for CORS. Therefore, you cannot consume it from your frontend. You'll have to proxy the API calls through a server that you control.

Comment: Be aware that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a _response_ header, not a _request_ header. Using that header in conjunction with `fetch` will lead you nowhere. Also, that you can read the response when visiting the URL in Chrome or in Postman is expected; CORS doesn't apply to those two cases, but it does apply to `fetch` calls

Comment: @jub0bs thank you! i created a node.js server and it works now!